# PHP Format long variables and place holder

Tags: php, csv, long-integer, placeholder

I am trying create an array of variables in different
types.

My aim is to create a .csv file to use with Canada Post Electronic Shipping Tools.
(code to create .csv file is not included here)

I am using Canada Post's Electronic Shipping Guide's 
**2.2.4 Import Orders Items Records - Layout Type 5** document.

I have to create 52 elements array and keep some "integer", "boolean","currency", "long", and "place holder values"  in the array.

My issues are.

1. How can I define **long** values?
2. What should I do to fill "place holder" values.

This is an example of place holder requirement.

Field NO:32,     Field:US Postal Box indicator        Type: Placeholder       Length: 1       Format Notes: “1” indicates that the field is blank.

Below is the code I use to create an array

```
<?php
$record_count_array = array();
//Create an integer value
$integer = 00;
$integer =  (integer)$integer ;
//Create a boolean value
$boolean = 1;
$boolean =  (boolean )$boolean  ;
//Fake long value -  Please lset me know your suggestions
$long    = 100000;
$string  = "string_value";
//Create a currency value
$currency = 10.00;
$currency = money_format('%i', $currency);
//Fake spaceholder value -  Please lset me know your suggestions
$placeholder = 2;
//Create a 52 item array
for($count = 0; $count< 52 ; $count++)
{
if($count == 0 || $count == 23 || $count == 47){
$record_count_array[] = $integer;
}
elseif($count == 18 || $count == 24 || $count == 25 || $count == 26) {
$record_count_array[] = $long;
}elseif($count == 27 || $count == 28 || $count == 29 || $count == 32
|| $count == 33 || $count == 34 || $count == 35 || $count == 36
|| $count == 37 || $count == 38 || $count == 39 || $count == 40
|| $count == 41 || $count == 44 || $count == 48 || $count == 49
|| $count == 50) {
$record_count_array[] = $boolean;
}elseif($count == 31 || $count == 42 || $count == 43) {
$record_count_array[] = $placeholder;
}elseif($count == 46) {
$record_count_array[] = $currency;
}
else{
$record_count_array[] = $string;
}
}
var_dump($record_count_array)."<br />";
?>
```

And this is the output I get (using var_dump())

```
array(52) 
{[0]=> int(0) [1]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[2]=> string(12) "string_value" [3]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[4]=> string(12) "string_value" [5]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[6]=> string(12) "string_value" [7]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[8]=> string(12) "string_value" [9]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[10]=> string(12) "string_value" [11]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[12]=> string(12) "string_value" [13]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[14]=> string(12) "string_value" [15]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[16]=> string(12) "string_value" [17]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[18]=> int(100000) [19]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[20]=> string(12) "string_value" [21]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[22]=> string(12) "string_value" [23]=> int(0) [24]=> int(100000) 
[25]=> int(100000) [26]=> int(100000) [27]=> bool(true) 
[28]=> bool(true) [29]=> bool(true) [30]=> string(12) "string_value" 
[31]=> int(2) [32]=> bool(true) [33]=> bool(true) 
[34]=> bool(true) [35]=> bool(true) [36]=> bool(true) 
[37]=> bool(true) [38]=> bool(true) [39]=> bool(true) 
[40]=> bool(true) [41]=> bool(true) [42]=> int(2) 
[43]=> int(2) [44]=> bool(true) 
[45]=> string(12) "string_value" [46]=> string(5) "10.00" 
[47]=> int(0) [48]=> bool(true) 
[49]=> bool(true) [50]=> bool(true) 
[51]=> string(12) "string_value" }
```

Can somebody guide me to

1. Format long variables correctly.
2. Understand what is "place holder" variable do and how to format them?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You can treat the long as integer, as PHP doesn't have the long type (AFAIK)
2 - For the placeholder, I don't know if I understood correctly the problem but I'd suggest you to take a look on `sprintf` (https://www.php.net/sprintf) to format the string.